# LibGDX - FreetypeFont not working on Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx, freetype

I'm using FreetypeFont in my LibGDX project.

The issue is that when I run my project on my computer, the text is showing up as expected whereas in my Android device the text is not showing correctly.

This is my code :

```
    // Font Loading
    FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    manager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    manager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".TTF", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter size3Params = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    size3Params.fontFileName = "UI/fonts/myFont.TTF";
    size3Params.fontParameters.size = (int) Constants.TITLE_FONT_SIZE;
    manager.load("sg3.TTF", BitmapFont.class, size3Params);
```

The result is the following:

In my Android device :

[image]

In my computer :

[image]

Comment: Maybe the screen is too small on your device? It looks as if the font is not scaled to acomodate for the screen size in the android screenshot

Comment: my android device is physically smaller but has more resolution than my computer

Comment: Did you try changing the font size though?

Comment: of course I did...

Comment: Could viewports be messing it up? It looks like the font on your android device is being stretched.